# Dynamically create diffrent components with diffrent components inside them

Tags: angular, typescript, dynamic, components

So i get a list with only names of the types of components i want to use. Eacht type of component has his own sub components. For example i have 3 diffrent components a car, a plane and a boat. I only get the names of the components and based on this i need to ask the api what properties of these components i need to change which gives me a json object back that look like this.

```
{
  "Engine":{
     "Horsepower":{
         "type": "input.text" 
      },
      "Torque":{
         "type": "input.slider"
      }
   }
}
```

Is there anyway i can create these components from json objects? I tried looking online but i only found awnser when the component only has 1 type of sub component.

[image]

Comment: I see no reason for the parent and the child component to be dynamically created. the way I see it can be a generic component. the only thing that may or may not be fit to be dynamically created is the form part and that can be achieved using reactive forms, or better, `ngx-formly` library. do make sure you're not over-engineering your solution and adding complexity where its not required. personally, for the simple case you described, I'd go with @input @output all the way.

Comment: Can you share what you have so far?